# Unterschiede zwischen "dahingehend" und "derartig"

Tags: difference

> Das Straßenverkehrsgesetz wurde am 30. März **dahingehend** geändert, **dass** sich der Fahrzeugführer zwar "vom Verkehrsgeschehen und der Fahrzeugführung abwenden" darf.

"Dahingehend dass" im Sinne von "so dass", "derartig, dass" findet man lediglich in  [Openthesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/dahingehend) 
Also gehe ich davon aus, dass das Wort in dieser Bedeutung eher nicht so geläufig ist. Sonst noch welche Unterschiede?

Comment: Ich behaupte, _dahingehend_ legt den Fokus auf das Ziel oder auch auf Beiläufigkeiten, die sich auf dem Weg zum Ziel ergeben. _Derartig_ erinnert eher an _in einer Art und Weise_ oder _auf eine Art und Weise_.

Comment: Ist m. E. mal wieder eine Beamten-und-Manager-Floskel, die überflüssig ist. Dein Vorschlag "so dass" ersetzt die Floskel völlig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zunächst muss ich widersprechen: **dahingehend dass** ist einigermaßen geläufig, wie auch die Liste der [Beispiele bei Linguee](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/wirkt+dahingehend,+dass.html) zeigt.

Es lässt sich auch nicht direkt durch die genannten **so dass** und **derartig dass** ersetzen, denn wie im Kommentar erwähnt haben alle drei zwar eine ähnliche Bedeutung, aber dahingehend beschreibt eher den Prozess / das Ziel, während **so** und **derartig** eher die (unausweichliche) Konsequenz einer Handlung beschreiben.

Oder anders ausgedrückt: Hinter **dahingehend** steht im Normalfall die direkte Absicht, ein bestimmtes Ziel mit einer Handlung zu erreichen, bei **so** und **derartig** ist es eine logische -aber unter Umständen unerwünschte- Konsequenz.

Comment: Das ist eine interessante Erklärung. Allerdings kann ich sie nicht mit dem konkreten Beispiel aus der Frage in Einklang bringen. Denn dort geht es ja darum, dass das StVG bereits geändert **wurde**, und zwar mit der **zitierten** Formulierung. - Wie kann es sich also noch um ein Ziel oder einen Prozess handeln?

Comment: Das StVG wurde mit dem Ziel geändert, dass sich der Fahrzeugführer zwar mehr abwenden darf.... Ich sehe da keinen Widerspruch. Ich kann ja auch eine Tätigkeit in der Vergangenheit durchgeführt haben, mit einem bestimmten Ziel, auch wenn das Ziel im Heute dadurch bereits erreicht wurde...

Comment: Ja, eine zielgerichtete Tätigkeit kann natürlich abgeschlossen bzw. vergangen sein. Die Funktion von "dahingehend dass" verstehe ich am obigen Beispiel leider immer noch nicht. - Ich versuche es mal mit anderen, einfacheren Beispielen: 1) "Ich bin so gelaufen, dass ich nichts umstoße." wäre das, was Deiner Erklärung in meinem Verständnis am nächsten kommt; aber "Ich bin dahingehend gelaufen, dass ich nichts umstoße." sagt man ja nicht. 2) "Er hat auf die Entscheidung dahingehend eingewirkt, dass ich straffrei rauskomme." Dieses Beispiel klappt mit "so dass" nicht. Das meinst Du wahrscheinlich.

Answer (score 2):

Ich muss zugeben, dass man selbst als Muttersprachler sich manchmal fragt, was dieses "dahingehend dass" einem außer "so dass" sagen soll. Mir fiele nämlich kein Unterschied ein.

In der Tat wird es im Vergleich zu "so dass" extrem selten verwendet; im Jahr 2000 wurde "dahingehend dass" laut [dieser Ngrams-Suche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dahingehend+dass%2Cso+dass%2CGesetzesentwurf&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdahingehend%20dass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20dass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGesetzesentwurf%3B%2Cc0) etwa 25.000 (in Worten fünfundzwanzig tausend) Mal **seltener** als "so dass" benutzt; selbst das Wort "Gesetzesentwurf" kam in dem Jahr etwa 2.500 Mal öfter als "dahingehend dass" vor.